# Custom button instead of the default button on the camera iphone 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I know you must do to take a picture with a button that was created by me and not the default one.

Also as you can remove the preview that comes after taking a photo?

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

- Use the [`showCameraControls` property of `UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/showsCameraControls) to show or hide the default controls
- Use the [`cameraOverlayView` property of `UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) to provide your own view to display atop of the camera view. You can then assign this property a custom UIView that will contain your own UIButtons
- Use the [`takePicture` action/method of `UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture) to ask the camera picker to take a picture. You will typically call this method in the action of your custom button.
- Read the documentation and the [Programming Guides](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010400) ;)